# Workaround for TLS

Tags: integration, rest, soap, tls

We are using a number of integration operations with different systems and some of those systems are not going to be updated to the TLS 1.1 cryptographic protocols or higher anytime soon. This systems will  probably remain on TLS 1.0 for a bit longer.

So I was wondering if there are any architectural works around to maintain any integration operation active between SFDC with any system that is not going to be using TLS 1.1 or hither cryptographic protocols.

Is there any way we can continue to use TLS 1.0 past the diablement date?

Comment: I can think of one option is to put a middleware which supports TLS 1.0 and above between your org and outside system.

Comment: SFSE is the right place. Middleware is a great idea and probably one of your only options.

Comment: Middleware is only solution, from my experience.

Comment: @saroj you should post that as an answer. It's short, but in this case exactly on point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a middleware which supports TLS 1.0 and above. The middleware will use TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 to interact with Salesforce on the other hand it can also interacts with systems which only supports TLS 1.0. In this way you can establish a connection from  Salesforce with those systems which only supports TLS 1.0.

Comment: Thank you Saroj. We will try something in this line, it looks like the best solution.