# TLS 1.0 Disabled in the organization

Tags: soap

when I am using SOAP UI to get the session Id for particular user in salesforce

it is showing error like:

[image]

for that I am checking for critical updates to enable the TLS 1.1 But it is not showing in my salesforce user

[image]
How to Rectify the error and please anyone guide me for the Answer and I am using sandbox

Comment: That update can not be disabled in sandbox anymore

Comment: @kurunve then why it is showing error,how to rectify the error

Comment: tl;dr; 1.0 is not supported anymore. SOAP UI uses 1.0
Main reason is because that update is forcing everyone to move from TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.1
SF announced that around year ago, and gave 3 month for SB for activation and 1 year for production activation. It is around 1 month left until it will be finally activated, so you would not be able to use this tool in production as well as you can not do that in sandbox.

Comment: How to use SOAP UI with TLS 1.2 can be found here -- https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-to-enable-TLS-1-2-in-SoapUI/td-p/96239

Comment: solution would be to read what has been done by other SOAP UI users in my previous link (append some parameter into SOAP UI to force it use newer TLS)

Comment: @user36188 Glad you got it worked out. If one of the answers posted led you to solving your issue, please help the rest of the community by marking it as having answered your question. That can be very helpful to anyone who searches this topic later looking for questions with accepted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather that try and roll back the Salesforce support for TLS 1.0 it is much easier and more productive to change SOAP UI to support TLS 1.2.

I did this by altering the `SoapUI-5.2.1.vmoptions` options in the bin directory that SOAP UI runs out of.

I added the following line to the end of that file:

```
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following:

- Review the [Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0](http://click.mail.salesforce.com/?qs=a0d77fb6ff3f6ddbed52b41f541461fc745cefcadd81f8b0738ed383f92e1263) article.
- Post your questions with issues you're having to the Official: [Salesforce Infrastructure](http://click.mail.salesforce.com/?qs=9647a03ea24bd6cf456a761295a49eeb4e10b077ed6027a4e2f3af81d76e30ac) Success Community group.
- There's also the following video [Secure Connections: How TLS 1.0 disablement impacts your organization](http://click.mail.salesforce.com/?qs=7ae03685021070490d454781fdcb314b0289e40fa8c290d52ac3a3ad337110f8) that explains the issues and what to do.
- Disablement takes effect on March 4th, 2017

Answer (score 1):

Note from the Knowledge article [Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?eid-ss-tc=&id=Salesforce):

> Sandbox orgs
>   June 25, 2016, at 9:30 AM PDT (16:30 UTC)
>
> After this date and time, all sandbox orgs -- whether existing, refreshed, or new -- will have TLS 1.0 automatically disabled and will require TLS 1.1 or later in HTTPS connections to or from the sandbox org. The "Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections" CRUC setting will not be available.

You cannot support 1.0 in a sandbox environment any more. Add mentioned in another thread today ([Workaround for TLS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/157519/2995)), your best (maybe only) bet is to implement a middleware layer which supports incoming 1.0 calls and can push calls out using a supported protocol.